# wp_set_object_term via js btn frontend

Tags: functions, custom-field, javascript, jquery

Hi I just copied some code to change a post custom field term by clicking on the btn with *#projects-pay-btn* id and work with it on frontend as end user, but it does not working.
when the user push the btn to pay, I want to change the field named = *project_status* change to the new value. There is the code, I hope someone could help me out.

```
function change_payment_status(){
        $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
        global $wpdb;
        $tbl = $wpdb->prefix."posts";
        $taxonomies = array( 'project_status');
        $statname = array(
    'name' => 'در انتظار تایید پرداخت',
    'slug' => 'payment_accept'
) ;
        
        try{
            wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $statname, $taxonomies, $append = false );
            
        }
        catch(Exception $e){}

        echo json_encode($res);
        die();
    }
        global $post;
        global $wp;
        echo '
            <script>
                var cur_url = "'.home_url( $wp->request ).'";
                var ajx_url = "'.admin_url('admin-ajax.php').'";
                var post_id = "'.$post->ID.'";
                jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                    jQuery("#projects-pay-btn").submit(function(e){
                        
                            jQuery.post(ajx_url,{action:"change_payment_status",post_id:post_id},function(data){
                                var arr = JSON.parse(data);
                                
                            });
                        }
                        return false;
                    );
                });
            </script>
        ';
```

Comment: This is a JS issue, not a WP issue.

Comment: Thank you for answering, so you mean the function would work properly? And I need to change my js?